# How to remove the parent div containing search text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove the div that contains search text. Before I had only ul and li and I used following line of code to remove that list.

### HTML

```
<div id="found-results">
    <div class="ui list found-result"></div>
</div>
```

I use append to add list to above html

```
$('.ui.list.found-result').filter(function() {
    return $.text([this]) === 'Tha Royal Natural Spa'; }).remove();
}
```

Now instead of li I have to use div. My innerHTML looks like this:

```
<div class="item" id="id_">
    <div class="content">
        <a class="header">Lawson 108 Mercury Tower</a>
        <div class="description">Pathum Wan Bangkok, 10330<i class="map marker icon"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui divider"></div>
<div class="item" id="id_">
    <div class="content">
        <a class="header">Tha Royal Natural Spa</a>
        <div class="description">Bang Rak Bangkok, 10500<i class="map marker icon"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui divider"></div>
```

How can I remove the parent div containing that search text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In your code, you have 2 items with the same ID. Never, ever do that. IDs are meant to be unique**

```js
$('#click').on('click', function() {
  var elem = $('.header').filter(function() {
      return ($.text([this]) === 'Tha Royal Natural Spa')
  }).parent().parent();
  
  if(elem.next().hasClass('divider')) elem.next().remove();
  elem.remove();
});
```

```css
.divider {
  background: red;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100px'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" id="id_1">
  <div class="content">
    <a class="header">Lawson 108 Mercury Tower</a>
    <div class="description">
      Pathum Wan Bangkok, 10330 <i class="map marker icon"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ui divider"></div>

<div class="item" id="id_2">
  <div class="content">
    <a class="header">Tha Royal Natural Spa</a>
     <div class="description">
         Bang Rak Bangkok, 10500<i class="map marker icon"></i>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ui divider"></div>


<br><br>

<button id="click">Remove</button>
```

Comment: your code is removing header only. But in my case i have header and description so i have to remove the parent div

Comment: @SS you should have made that clear in your question. Anyway, I have changed the code to remove the next divider after the element

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
$( "div:contains('Tha Royal Natural Spa')" ).remove()
```